# CNAME and MX records on naked domain

Tags: email, dns, google-workspace, cname

I have a domain (registered with Daily.co.uk) that for quite a while was set up with a CNAME pointed to my friend's webserver which uses dynamic DNS to resolve to his IP, in addition to MX records pointed to my Google Apps setup. I've recently realised that this is an invalid configuration and that it was causing issues where certain email servers couldn't send to my address. If I could I'd use the IP of the webserver as the A record, but it's dynamic. I could use something like WWWizer to force a redirect to the www host, but I'd prefer not to do that especially considering I have a nice three letter domain :)

Is there a way I could forward everything to the webserver with the CNAME record and then somehow redirect the MX records from there? Or would I have to set up a mail server to redirect it?

For what it's worth, the domain is http://malachy.org.uk which I eventually am going to alias with http://mal.so in the same way.

Comment: do you only have MX records pointing to google aps, or do you also have a MX record poiting to the domain name, which is a cname record? If you only have google apps servers as MX records, then having CNAME record for domain, which points to dyndns doesn't make any effect on mail delivery towards you domain, AFAIK. If you have CNAME also as MX record, remove it, and only leave google apps as MX.

Comment: The MX records all point to Google Apps, yes. But the @ root host as a CNAME record seems to override this in some cases and I'm lead to believe that these cases are the ones following the standard strictly. I confirmed being able to send email when I couldn't previously after experimenting by setting an A record rather than a CNAME.

Comment: if you go to http://mxtoolbox.com/ and do a MX lookup of your domain, does it only return google aps servers, or also your @ record?

Comment: It is currently only returning the Google Apps entries - and I think the changes have propagated to reset it to a CNAME. But I have a delivery failure email confirming that some servers see only the CNAME... and in fact other domain name management tools I've used won't let me set separate CNAME and MX records for the same host.

Comment: I replicated the same setup (@ CNAME, @ MX) on a 123-reg hosted domain and host -t mx returns as just an alias of the webserver. Seems to confirm to me that this setup is nonstandard.